# Can't access shared memory in arm64 assembly language

Tags: assembly, arm64

I have the following routine:

```
getSharedMemory:                            // x0 => digits                     
    push2   x29, x30                        // push FP & LR     
    mov     x29, x0                         // x29 => digits

    mov     x0, #key_digits
    mov     x1, #FOUR
    mov     x2, 0666
    bl      shmget
    cmp     w0, wzr                         // x0 = shmid
    bmi     gsm_end

    mov     x1, xzr
    mov     x2, xzr
    bl      shmat
    cmp     x0, MINUS_ONE
    beq     gsm_end
    str     x0, [x29]                       // save shared mem

gsm_end:    
    pop2    x29, x30                        // pop fb & lr
    ret
```

`createSharedMemory` looks just like this, except for the `IPC_CREAT | 0666`.

I have 2 assembly language programs. One creates the shared memory and the other gets it.
When I call `getSharedMemory` or `createShareMemory` I do this:

```
adr x0, digits
bl  getSharedMemory
```

and expect to find the pointer to memory in digits.
I also write 4 0 bytes into the shared memory after creating it.

Each of my two programs has:

```
.section .data
  digits:    .dword 0
```

When I try to access the shared memory, I do this:

```
adr x12, digits
```

I use the debugger to see if it has 4 zeros (x/4b $x12) and I see random numbers and not the 4 zeros. I've tried the suggested modification:

```
adrp  x12, digits
add   x12, x12, #:lo12:digits
```

I put the mod where I create the shared mem and where I access it, but I'm still not seeing my 4 zeros.

Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You don't show how you write your zeroes. Also `x/4b $x12` is wrong as `x12` contains the address of `digits` and `digits` contains the address of your shared memory block. That `x` command will just print that address, not the zeroes you have written there (if you did that correctly).

Comment: Can you please format your post with [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)?